# Regular expressions in R that apply only from nth word on

Tags: r, regex

In R regular expressions, how could one have a regex evaluated not from the beginning of the target strings, but instead only from the nth word on?

For example, suppose one is interested in substituting any numbers in a string with the symbol
`@`. Then one could use `gsub("\\d+", "@", string)`, like in:

```
gsub("\\d+", "@", "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again")
```

The result would be:

```
> "words before @ then more words then @ again"
```

Now, keeping up with that example, using regex, how could one make it so that only numbers that appear starting from the 4th word in the string would get substituted? So that the above example would return `"words before 879 then more words then @ again"` because `879` is the 3rd word in the target string?

FWIW, I found many questions on extracting and locating words, some on matching from the beginning versus from the end, some on getting the substring up to or from the nth word. But none on how exactly to only have regular expressions disregard the first n words of a string when looking for a pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this with `perl=TRUE` (double backslashes in R):

```r
^\s*(?:\S+\s*){3}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\d+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/70gcIJ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (3 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){3}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL)           skip the match, search for next match
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
```

**Example code sample**:

```r
gsub("^\\s*(?:\\S+\\s*){3}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\\d+", "@", "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again", perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is very good an intuitive base R solution. Since I'm interested in learning it for general purposes, one follow-up question: how could that be altered to also work for instance with `strcapture`. Say one is interested in returning the first number found after the nth word? Per your explanation I thought the following would suffice, but does not: `strcapture("^\\s*(?:\\S+\\s*){4}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\\d+)", "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again", list(col1 = character()))`

Comment: @SvanK `strcapture("^\\s*(?:\\S+\\s*){4}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(\\d+)", "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again", list(col1 = character()), perl=TRUE)` seems to work - you forgot the `perl=TRUE` here.

Comment: damn it! Of course, sorry about that. So yeah, your solution cleanly works with all regex related functions I have tried. Many thanks

Comment: oh, I forgot one case, for completion, if you don't mind: given the usage of `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`, how could one group the regex such as to also capture what came before the matched number after the nth word? For example: `strcapture("^(\\s*(?:\\S+\\s*){4}(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(\\d+)", "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again", list(col1 = character(), col2 = character()), perl=TRUE)` returns "" and "1001" instead of "words before 879 then more words then " and "1001".

Comment: @SvanK I think you needn't use the skip-fail here, the `strcapture("^\\s*((?:\\S+\\s*){4})\\D*(\\d+)", "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again", list(col1 = character(),col2 = character()), perl=TRUE)` should work.

Answer (score 4):

We could create a `proto` function in `gsubfn` to count the words and replace

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("\\w+", proto(fun = function(this, x) if(count > 3)
          sub("\\d+", "@", x) else x), str1)
#[1] "words before 879 then more words then @ again"
```

One of the advantage is that it can insert/replace at any word count or can have replacements at multiple word counts i.e. suppose we want to replace only words between 4 and 6

```
gsubfn("\\w+", proto(fun = function(this, x) if(count  %in% 4:6)
         sub("\\d+", "@", x) else x), str1)
```

or a more complex case

```
gsubfn("\\w+", proto(fun = function(this, x) if(count  %in% c(4:6, 12:15))
      sub("\\d+", "@", x) else x), str2)
#[1] "words before 879 then @ replace not 1001 again and replace @ and @"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "words before 879 then more words then 1001 again"
str2 <- "words before 879 then 50 replace not 1001 again and replace 1003 and 1005"
```